# SMTP Server unable to send mails

Tags: oracle, email, oracle11g, smtp

I have an SMTP Server Setup on Windows server 2003 R2 on my domaiin.

This is when I receive the mail:

1. When I send a mail using a txt file placed inside the Pickup folder of the mailroot I receive the mail.
2. When I write a Pl/SQL Block to send mail.

This is when I don't receive a mail:

1. When I try to send a mail from an Oracle 11g Package, the log files in the SMTP Server shows the following:

```
    14:39:59 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX HELO - 250
    14:39:59 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX MAIL - 250
    14:39:59 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX RCPT - 250
    14:39:59 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX DATA - 250
    14:39:59 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX QUIT - 240
    14:39:59 YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY - - 0
    14:39:59 YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY - - 0
    14:39:59 YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY EHLO - 0
    14:39:59 YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY - - 0
    14:41:00 YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY - - 0
    14:41:00 YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY EHLO - 0
    14:41:00 YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY - - 0
    14:42:00 YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY - - 0
    14:42:00 YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY EHLO - 0
    14:42:00 YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY - - 0
    14:43:00 YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY - - 0
    14:43:00 YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY EHLO - 0
    14:43:00 YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY - - 0
```

Can somebody please explain what does this response mean. And why am I not getting these mails.

2. Also, when I send a mail from an Oracle Apex application, I don't receive it. The Apex admin mail log logs the mail but I donot receive it in my mail box.
   Please Help!!!

Thanks in Advance
Cheers!!!

Comment: Maybe you could show the package code that is trying to send mail?

Answer (score 0):

Realized that the Mime Header was malformed hence the SMTP Server that I setup wasn't accepting the mails and all the mails went to the BADMAIL folder.

Anyways....

Thanks for the response.